# Best way to clone private git gem repo using Dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
   # Dockerfile

   FROM rails:onbuild
```

And `docker-compose.yml` is something like this:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
  links:
    - db
```

So When I run `docker-compose run web rake db:create db:migrate`, it fails to clone private git repository. So my question is what is the best way to clone private git repo using Dockerfile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how we could fetch private gem using `Doockerflie` configuration or adding command in it.

Maybe we have to grant access permission using `Personal Access Token`. Here is the steps:

- Generate `Personal Access Token` for your private gem
- Define gem's `git` location using this pattern of `url`

  `gem 'your_private_gem', git: "https://your_token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/your_private_gem.git"`
- Maybe to make it more secure you could use some `.env` file (gem 'dotenv') to define this token in this way:

  `gem 'your_private_gem', git: "https://#{ENV[GITHUB_TOKEN]}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/your_private_gem.git"`

Hope it would help. Or I'm finding new more secure way, so following this question. Cheers!